# Copying and overwriting some resources with maven in a profile

Tags: java, maven, build, resources, copy

I have two projects which are built from one maven multiproject, project A and project B. Project B recently came to live and differ only little from project A, namely it uses a couple of different configuration files. My idea was to create a profile for projectB and add additional configuration files / replace existing configuration files. I've tried several approaches on stackoverflow including copy-rename plugin and mvn dependency plugin. Part of the problem seems to be that both projects have a file with same config name.

My current/last approach was to use maven-resources-plugin in following way:
I created an additional directory: src/main/projectbresources and a projectbprofile:

```
        <profile>
        <id>projectb</id>
        <activation><activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault></activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <!-- here the phase you need -->
                            <phase>validate</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/projectbresources</directory>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
            </build>
    </profile>
```

I have a file with same name in both src/main/resources and src/main/projectbresources however, no matter the profile I build with, always the file from src/main/resources is in the target folder. Additional files that are in projectbresources only are copied to target.

Comment: Why do you have the same file in two locations? The question is what is inside the file ? And what you like to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your statement "*Project B recently came to live and differ only little from project A, namely it uses a couple of different configuration files.*" I would say you don't need 2 separate projects. You can have only one project and based on activated profile choose different configurations. With this approach the configuration files for both cases can have same name but different content.

Your project structure will look like (as an example):

project root folder:

```
pom.xml
- src
-- main
--- resources-profileA
--- resources-profileB
```

Now, the pom.xml contains 2 profiles: profileA and profileB. Each profile define it's own build/resources.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>projectA</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-profileA</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>projectB</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-profileB</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

More on that, you can make one profile active by default. This will help your dev environment to automatically use one. If you like to have a default active profile for that profile you can name the resource folder just *resources* (default maven name) and keep different name for second profile.

UPDATE:

To go 'easy' and only add some additional files, you can use for profile projectA the maven defaults and define onle a profile for projectB.

The project root folder become:

```
pom.xml
- src
-- main
--- resources
--- resources-profileB
```

and the pom.xml will contains only one profile inactive by default:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>projectB</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources-profileB</directory>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

How to build for the two profiles:
Build for no profile is equivalent of building for projectA:

> mvn clean install

Buid for projectB profile will ignore resources in default folder and will use only resources defined in profile (src/main/resources-profileB).

> mvn clean install -P projectB

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I understand that I can make two profiles with two sets of resources... I wanted to go 'easy' and only add some additional files for project B without changing project A build at all. But if everything else fails I will go back to two profiles as you suggested.

Comment: @Leon I updated my response with what I think is the 'easiest' solution from your perspective.

Comment: this was my first approach, but instead of copying project B resources on top of project A it overwrote resource settings and only project B resources were included. But I am tending to fall back to two explicit folder solution thus making it explicit to have shared and project specific configs

Comment: Ok, I figured it out in the end, I ended up with creating two directories for projecta and projectb respectively, and two maven profiles, but the one for projecta activated by default. So all existing jenkins jobs etc could build projecta same way as before, and new jobs can build projectb. BTW, I am using maven-resources-plugin copy-resources.

Comment: @Leon I'm glad I help you.